# Flutter - push firebase notifications to specific users without firebase auth

Tags: firebase, flutter, notifications, firebase-authentication, push

I am working with Firebase to push notifications and I don't use Firebase authentication on my app (I have my own system).

I didn't find an answer to this question:
Is it possible to push notifications to a specific user with firebase without Firebase authentication (and therefore, without a UID)? How?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The push notifications are not sent based on user, they are sent based on push notification token that is received when you register for push notifications (iOS & Android).

The push notification token will change in the case of uninstall/install and has nothing to do with what user is logged in in the app, you can send push notifications to apps that don't have users at all.

In order to target a specific user with push notification, you must do something called `user segmentation`, that is, filter user based on particular properties of these users. In general user segmentation is done by tracking user action and user properties and depends on the push notification platform in use. For example you can track user actions in the app, like `user added product to cart`, `user has x products in cart` and then send a push notification to `all users that have more than 3 products in cart`.

All the push notifications platform link the push notification token to the events triggered.

If you are using firebase, the most easiest way is to track user properties, there are a lot of tutorials on this part. Although, in my opinion, firebase tracking is kind of crappy.

One thing to note, since the push notification token is not linked to the user directly, in case there are two users (two accounts) using the same device they, they will receive push notifications on the same device, so don't send sensitive information via push notifications.

Comment: Hi danypata, thank you for informations ! Unfortunatly, I really need to push notification to specific users, user segmentation is not enough in my case. I'll take a look at OneSignal to do that. If I find something I will share it here

Comment: You can send your user id as a user property, then you'll do something ```send push to the user with id```. Or you can track the user id and then send the push based on a segmentation that uses the user id.

Comment: Ok, finally, as you propose, I used the registration token that I can have by doing firebaseMessaging.getToken() or by .refreshToken.
I tried to send notifications to these specific devices by passing "to": "registration token" and it works.
But now, there is the problem you said about two users on the same device. I will handle it myself.
Thank you for you help, have a good day. :)

Comment: What about if you are using web push notifications? How do I get the users token using javascript? I can't seem to find anything.